# unexpected margins for html elements

Tags: javascript, css, margin, offset, page-layout

Why `document.body.style.margin` returns me nothing in chrome and firefox if the
style="margin:[some] px" is not set for body.

Now suppose I want the margins of body using `offsetParent.offsetLeft` css property by some child Element of div.It gives me 0px by default.Well if the body element is initially at default 0px margin then why does my html visual elements are displayed with some margin from left of the page which comes out to be 8px.

Is the body margin 0 px only??

**HTML** :

```
<div>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:green;
    border:2px solid green;
    padding:10px 10px
}

p {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
    background:yellow
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E9VMP/)

Comment: `document.body.style.margin` does not give you the full _computed_ style.

Comment: If you use Notepad++ default type of encoding is UTF-8 with BOM, so what type of encoding you use ? try UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: If you have problems with jsFiddle use Normalized CSS, in Fiddle Options http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/E9VMP/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try using [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) :

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).margin
```

Inspect the elements to see where the additional offset might be getting in from.

Comment: Please post your code to get detailed help, here. We cannot magically guess where those offsets come from in your page.

Comment: <body><div style="height:200px;width:200px;background:green;border:2px solid green;padding:10px 10px"><p style="height:100px;width:100px;padding:10px 0 0 10px;background:yellow">hello</p></div>

Comment: My code is this easy i just wanted to get document.write(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].offsetParent.offsetLeft);

Comment: To get better answers always make the question presentable (I edited your question with the code). Besides I  couldn't find any margins with the body tag.

Comment: thanks for the edit.. What no margins isnt your div staarting at some margin from browser window

Answer (score 1):

From the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#offset-attributes):

"If the element is the HTML body element ... return zero and terminate this algorithm."

The `body` has an 8px margin because that's the default in Chrome. But it returns 0 for `offsetParent.offsetLeft` because it has to ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Ques1:**

Because [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information#DOM_Style_Object) is an object representing the inline style of the element. If you haven't set the inline style, you can't get a value from it either.

**Ques2**

[`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft) property is related to its [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent) element, which is necessarily not the `body` element. Also, `offsetParent` may refer to a different element in different browsers, also the [`Box Model`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) is different, and `margin` or other properties may or may not applied within the calculations.

---

**EDIT**

Obviously `body` has some default margin, but it seems to be difficult to catch it. Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ6ZN/1/), you'll find the margins of the `body`.

A short abstract from the results of the fiddle:

```
var elem = document.body;
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('color')); // rgb(0, 0, 0)
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('marginBottom')); // null or an empty string, depends on the browser
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).marginBottom); // Suprise! 8px
```

As you can see in your console, `margin` is empty. It would be empty even when you would have assigned a value to it. This is because it's not a real member of the CSSStyleCollection, `margin` is just a shortcut to set all the properties within a single line. The same stands for example for `border`.

Comment: for the elements inside the div element it is body element.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].offsetParent just came out to be <body>

Comment: i just want to know that body element has some default margin or not